# Which WCF services can you add a service reference to in WP7 Mango?

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, windows-phone-7

Just need to know when adding a service reference to a WCF service in a mango silverlight project which types of WCF services (webHttpBinding, WSBinding etc) will visual studio generate a proxy for automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supported standard bindings are `basicHttpBinding` - with security mode of either None, Transport or TransportWithMessageCredentials (for username/password over HTTPS), or `customBinding`. The binding element supported are username/password security, binary/text encodings and http/https transports. You can actually use `wsHttpBinding` as well, if you disable message security and reliable messaging (it's roughly equivalent to a custom binding with text encoding + http transport).

Ah, and to be able to add a service reference, you'll need to enable metadata on the service (it's the default on the VS templates).